# Join two data sets based on one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data sets (DF1, DF2) of uneven rows and I am trying to merge the two using the unique ID column that is present in both data sets. My condition is that I only want rows with matching IDs that is present in both DF1 and DF2, meaning if there are IDs in DF2 that's not in DF1, they will be removed and vice versa. As well I want all the corresponding columns from DF1 and DF2 to be in the new DF3.

I tried to do a semi_join but it only includes the columns from DF1 and not DF2. As well inner_join returns the data with 50000 variables which does not work because DF1 contains 40,000 variables and DF 2 90,000 variables so the result should be less than 40,000 variables.

```
test <- semi_join(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "ID")  
test2 <- inner_join(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "ID")
```

DF 1 and 2 are given and DF3 is my desired result.

```
DF1
ID                  Name                     Date
1 98251           MacDonald, Nich 100000    2013/07/21      
2 98252           John, B~ 100000           2013/06/10    
3 98253           Larry, B~ 100000          2013/04/13

DF2
ID                  Name                     Action
1 98252           Bond, Nich 100000         Eat     
2 98253           John, B~ 100000           Eat   
3 98256           Larry, B~ 100000          Eat            

DF3
ID                  Name                     Date                Action    
2 98252           John, B~ 100000           2013/06/10             Eat
3 98253           Larry, B~ 100000          2013/04/13             Eat
```

`

Comment: This should work `merge(DF1, DF2, by = "ID")`. Your dplyr joins work, too. Please provide example data that fails the merge.

Comment: When you say "variables", I assume you mean rows? Almost certainly you have duplicate IDs in at least one of your data frames. Look at `any(duplicated(DF1$ID))` and `any(duplicated(DF2$ID))` to confirm - `TRUE` means there are duplicates, `FALSE` means no duplicates. Look at `tail(sort(table(DF1$ID)))` for a few examples of duplicates (and same for `DF2`).

Comment: You can join `DF1` to the *first* matching record in `DF2` if you do `inner_join(DF1, DF2[!duplicated(DF2$ID), ])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As well inner_join returns the data with 50000 variables which does
>   not work because DF1 contains 40,000 variables and DF 2 90,000
>   variables so the result should be less than 40,000 variables.

The reason inner join produces more rows (you used variables: assuming you mean rows) than those in DF1 is because if inner_join matches multiple matches, it returns all such combinations as extra 10k rows. as described in join{dplyr}:
[image]

So what you need to do is use unique by 'ID':

```
test2 <- unique(inner_join(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "ID"),by = "ID")
```

You will end up getting 40k rows in test2. However, what we are doing is removing all the 2nd matches of ID onwards, in case there are multiple matches. If you want to remove in the reverse order: use instead:

```
test2 <- unique(inner_join(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "ID"),by = "ID",fromLast= TRUE)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Much more efficient to do `unique` of `DF2` *before* the join rather than doing the duplicated join and then deduplicating.